# Jenkins pipeline: can I share stashes between pipelines / workspaces?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have declarative `pipeline_a` executing `pipeline_b` via `build job`. Problem is `pipeline_b` needs to use some files generated by `pipeline_a`. `stash/unstash` works for me to share data between stages but stashes saved in `pipeline_a` do not seem to be visible in `pipeline_b`.

- Is this by design?
- Should I be using some other Jenkins trick to share files between different jobs/pipelines?

Comment: archive artifacts of `pipeline_a` and download it in `pipeline_b`

Comment: @FCh, Correct me if I'm wrong but description of the [copyartifact](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact) plugin suggests that the upstream project has to be completed before artifacts can be copied. This may work with sequentially executed jobs that can be triggered one after the other but not with an arbitrary `build job` call.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but there is a way around this. If call `archive()`, you can construct link to your artifact before completion: `${env.JENKINS_URL}/job/$jobName/$buildNumber/artifact/$artifactName`

Comment: @FCh Nice! Looks like `artifacts` is the way to go when sharing files between jobs and stash should be used only within the same pipeline.  I used the `upstream()` selector to get artifacts from the caller job (`pipeline_a` in my case) for convenience. Do you want to write a formal answer to this one?

Comment: if you insist, then I will do)

Comment: hehe, I'd write it but don't want to steal you thunder

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For share between jobs you can use [Copy Artifacts plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact) or `archive()` artifacts of `pipeline_a` and download it in `pipeline_b`:

Pipeline_a:

```
archive('artifactName')
```

Pipeline_b:

```
sh("wget ${env.JENKINS_URL}/job/$jobName/$buildNumber/artifact/$artifactName")
```

Comment: How to use archive()? I don't find information about this function. Can you share a link or an example to archive multiple files please? Thanks!